# Loading UIViews into an Array and then using them

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, nsarray

I am trying to create an array of views that I can then swipe though in my applicant.

I have tried to set up my array in my view did load then load the first view in the array into view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.title = @"Prototype";
    //Initalizse the swipe gestuer listener
    [self setupLeftSwipeGestureRecognizer];
    [self setupRightSwipeGestureRecognizer];

    //alloc and init viewcontroller nibs
    self.detailViewA = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
    self.detailViewB = [[DetailViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewControllerB" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.detailViewC = [[DetailViewControllerC alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewControllerC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    // Create Array
    viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:detailViewA_, detailViewB_, detailViewC_, nil];

    // set detail View as first view
    [self.view addSubview:[viewArray objectAtIndex:0]];

}
```

After which it crashes. and produces this message.

```
2012-05-31 10:06:33.769 SMPrototypeB[2394:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x131b00'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a view controller as a subview but what you need to do is add the view of that viewController.

```
UIViewController *tempVC = (UIViewController*)[viewArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubView:tempVC.view];
```

Comment: Would it make a difference if I am loading this stuff onto the current view? The thing is I have one masterview which handles animation for 3 other views, that get loaded in as subviews... if that makes sense.

Comment: If you have a master view controller that you are loading the views of other view controllers onto you should be fine. It is a good practice in my opinion especially if you want to separate out the logic for each view controller. You will actually want to cast the individual viewControllers in your array to "ViewController" so that you can access them in an array. My code sample will only work for your first element.

Comment: okay thanks.. I will continue researching with the information you have given me.. I'm still not quite understanding it.. but a little more reading and I will get there.

Comment: Its hard to give you too much with the small code snippet provided but I think you are on your way.

Comment: yep, I understand. I have the whole project in my dropbox.. but I have only just started trying to work these views into an array so I didn't think to post the link.

Comment: what dose casting viewControllers mean?.. sorry probably a dumb question but thats about the only thing I stuck in in your previous commetn.

Comment: I just mean when accessing a view controller within your array you will need to access each as it's base class since they are are all different types. I will update my answer to reflect what i mean.